# Convert rails activerecord to raw sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In php codeigniter FW, I can do it easily by using get_compiled_select() method.

Is there any method that I can convert the query build by active record to raw sql.
Ex:

```
User.find_by_name("abc")
```

should return raw query script something like

```sql
select * from user where name = "abc"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `to_sql` (it gives you a sql query string, and can be called on any ActiveRecord association):

```
User.find_by_name("abc").to_sql
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql

Comment: Update: It works for Where clause only at the moment, not for the finder queries.